# HTML.ActionLink Button Issue

Tags: html, button, model-view-controller

I currently have a button that is functioning a little strange. Whenever you click right in the middle of the button, it works and carries on the requested action. However, if you click anywhere near the outside border of the button, then the action doesn't get carried out.

Here is the current code:

```
     @if(mode == "Edit"){
            <div class="Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger">
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete Profile", "Delete", "GPS",  new { Id = Model.provider.Company.Id.Value, oem = Model.provider.Id}, 
            new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this provider? 
            All GPS Devices attributed to this provider will be removed as well.')" })</button></div>  
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the resulting HTML of your code you will see the following structure:

```
<div>
<button>
    <a></a>
</button>
</div>
```

Your event `onclick` is only attached to the `<a>` tag, so if you click in any place inside the `<button>` but outside the `<a>`, the action won't be fired.

By default `<a>` tags are inline, it means (among other things) its size is defined by its content so it won't fullfill the `<button>`, you can see this visually using the inspect tools from any brosers (like Chrome Developer Tools).

You can fix this using CSS to change the dimensions of your `<a>` tag. Try with `display:block`, `width` and `height`.

The final answer will depend on your other style rules.

Comment: However, I have some concerns related to nesting `<a>` in `<buttons>`. Shouldn't you only use `<a>` and style it as a button? or use button and forms?  But these are questions more related to definition then a practical approeach, when to use `<a>`, `<buttons>` and things like that. Welcome to HTML5.

Comment: Would that just be adding something like this? It doesn't seem to be working.                           .Delete a{
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 110px;
            height: 3px;
            }